# Is there a way to highlight selected string in both views using Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

Notepad++ highlights all occurrences of selected text in file. Is there a way to make selected text be highlighted in multiple views?

For example.

I have 2 views.

In view 1 I have this text:

```
one one two one one two one one
```

In 2nd view I have this text

```
three three three three two three two
```

Is there a way to make Notepad++ highlight string 'two' in view 1 and view 2 if I select it in view 1?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is now present as setting **Highlight another view** in Notepad++'s Preferences on **Highlighting** page:

[image]

(It is possible it wasn't there at time when you asked.)